# How to improve IDEA performance while editing big JSON files?

Tags: java, json, performance, intellij-idea

I'm working with some *big* JSON files in IDEA. When I say *big* I mean **>50k lines** (but barely **1MB**). These files are expected to grow, but IDEA is already having performance issues (slow navigation and edition).

If I open one of these files with Notepad++ for example it can be edited and navigated through with no issues at all, so I guess IDEA can be tweaked somehow so there are no issues with it.

Any idea on how to improve this?

Comment: I would suggest asking Jetbrains directly as they might have an answer. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/oauth?state=%2Fissues%2FIDEA

Comment: I agree with Peter - you are asking about a problem with a very specific product. I chances are really low that anybody here can do anything about the performance of IntellJ. If that doesn't work out: simply consider using different tooling. It wouldn't surprise me if other products such as SlickEdit or sublime would outperform "java focused" IDEs for specific use cases.

Comment: You are using a tool for what is was not built for here! It would be weird for  a single java file of even a configuration file to be 1 MB large, so the IDE was not optimized for that usage.